# How can I get a Click Performance Report from the Adwords API with just a Management account?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, google-ads-api

It's my first time using the Adwords API, and I'm trying to set up a call that downloads the Click Performance account for an account. I'm getting the

> "CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH"

error when I make the call, which seems to be because the account is a manager account, which according to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#ReportDefinitionError.CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH) is not able generate reports. All help I've found so far says to use CustomerService to get a list of your available accounts, and then use one of the non-manager accounts to make the report request. However when I try this I find no other accounts - see code below:

```
    Dim adw As New AdWordsUser

    Dim service As CustomerService = CType(adw.GetService(AdWordsService.v201806.CustomerService), CustomerService)

    Dim responses As New List(Of ReportResponse)

    Dim customers As Customer() = service.getCustomers()

    For Each c As Customer In customers

        Dim config As New AdWordsAppConfig() With {.ClientCustomerId = c.customerId.ToString}

        Dim user As New AdWordsUser(config)

        Dim report As New ReportUtilities(user, definition)

        responses.Add(report.GetResponse())

    Next
```

When I break in the For loop 'customers' only has the one member - the manager account. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something about how accounts work - it seems strange that a manager account cannot generate reports.

Have I missed something basic here?

Edit: I'm using Adwords v201806

Comment: It looks like you need an individual account linked to that manager account (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7456530?hl=en-GB). Can you delve further into your Customers tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of solved, hopefully my experience can be of some use to people having the same problem:

Ultimately I got around this issue by logging into the Adwords site and getting the clientID of the relevant accounts there, hardcoding that in, and making the API calls with a User object instantiated with that clientID.

Vivek's answer helped me understand why manager accounts can't make report calls, but I'm still at a loss as to why my original code only ever found the Manager account, and not any of the advertiser accounts that I can see on the Adwords site

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download report from Manager Account.

#### Reason

First you need to know what is Manager Account?

- it is used to manage advertiser account for easy accessing, consolidate billing, dashboard for linked accounts.
- it is *NOT* used to make any ads, rather it is only used for management of adwords account.

As there is no ad associated with Manager Account, you cannot query report for the same and rather query report for advertiser account and,

hence you'll receive `CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH` error indicating use of Manager Account being used for fetching report.

#### Solution

- use `canManageClients` flag from `Customer` to verify whether account is Manager Account or not. api doc [link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201806/CustomerService.Customer#canmanageclients)
- link advertiser account and query report for the same.

*(Refer official documentation [here](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7654391?hl=en&visit_id=1-636643422193672509-1777841589&rd=1))*

Comment: It's clear from @Sam's original post that he is aware of the restriction on manager accounts. The question is more focused on how to get the report from the manager account (i.e. how to get to an account that _can_ get a report)...

Comment: @oliver-clare yes you're right about @Sam's question, but there is no way you can get report using Manager Account's credentials, unless you've linked any account to that with at least reporting access and my answer justify why one can't download report with `Just` Manager Account.

Comment: You make a fair point and I didn't downvote your answer because it's still valid and useful. Is it a simple process to link an account in the way you mention? Perhaps if you included some steps to achieve this, yours would be the best answer here.